# Pandas throwing an OSError on PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, winapi, jetbrains-ide

I have been getting the following error on my PyCharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Boston-Kaggle/Boston.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Users\security\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Its because of my Pandas import:

`import pandas as pd`

As per suggestions on similar S/O posts, I have uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled it.  I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling `pandas` as well but nothing worked.

Comment: It looks like a 32/64 bit mix problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `***\core\__init__.py: line23` The initialization script loads a dll, located at your path: `"C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\.libs\*openblas*dll"`, If you're using a 32bit DLL with 64bit Python, or vice-versa, then you'll probably get errors.
I recommend trying to load your DLL(download from Numpy) with Anaconda in the same bits.

Comment: Yea but idk anything about DLLs.

Comment: which bit version of your numpy installed? and which bit is your python?

Comment: Could you find the `*openblas*dll`, and check its bit version with tool: Dependency Walker(find the "CPU" property of the DLL), and use the code `import platform
platform.architecture()` to get the python bits.

Comment: Is there a way to just uninstall and then reinstall?

Comment: Uninstall Anaconda and reinstall the other Anaconda bit version, or try to Uninstall Anaconda only and compiler it directly without reinstall.